# Digest::SHA1::hexdigest producing different hashes for same string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, encryption, sha1

I'm trying to do simple user authentication, but the call to `Digest::SHA1::hexdigest` in the sessions controller is producing a different hash than the one in the user model.

user.rb:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save {|user| user.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.password)}
    ...

    end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
    def create
        user = User.where(:username => params[:username], :password => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(params[:password])).first
    end
```

is there any way to fix this?

For example, the string, "password", when I try to login shows up as "5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8".

However, in the database, the same string, "password", shows up as:
"353e8061f2befecb6818ba0c034c632fb0bcae1b"

Comment: Do you have a real example? The same string generating different hashes?

Comment: @airplaneman19 Highly unlikely unless you using some sort of salt to encrypt it. but in your case i guess you are not. I doubt your `param[:password]` is same from the user.password i guess has some additional character like `spaces` etc that causing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before_save runs any time you save, so on create you encrypt, and then on any updates you're encrypting (the already encrypted one) again. Try using before_create.